# Creating a navigation tree with Django ListView

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

I'm working on my navigation for a django project and can't figure this one out. I have the context being returned from a single `ListView` class, but I want to arrange the returned queryset by a category.

If I have multiple categories in the same model, how can I split the returned view objects in order to display them separately on the page?

I tried using this in **views.py**:

```
class ServiceView(ListView):
    model = Service
    template_name = "services/services.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['health'] = Service.objects.all().filter(service_type__icontains='health')
        context['life'] = Service.objects.all().filter(service_type__icontains='life')
        return context
```

I was under the impression I could call the modified contexts from a template, but i could only call one context.  Is it possible to create multiple contexts from a single model?

I was trying to use a template like the following **services.html**:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav animated fadeIn">
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#coll-css" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Health</a>
        <ul id="coll-css" class="menu-submenu list-unstyled collapse">
            {% for service in health %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'services' %}{{ service.slug }}"><i class="fa {{ service.icon }}"></i>{{ service.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#coll-css" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Life</a>
        <ul id="coll-css" class="menu-submenu list-unstyled collapse">
            {% for service in life %}
                    <li><a href="{% url 'services' %}{{ service.slug }}"><i class="fa {{ service.icon }}"></i>{{ service.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The items under the "health" context populate, but not the life context.  Is it possible to use 2 for loops in a template?  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: it's totally correct what you've done. so what's the problem? you can have multiple variables sent through context, and it's not a problem to use more than one for loop in template, you can have as much as you want

Comment: @JohnMarcus are you sure there is data in both querysets? Have you tried `print(Service.objects.filter(service_type__icontains='life').count())` to see if the correct data is fetched?

Comment: @Ralf The problem is that I don't get any items back from the 'life' context.  Checking the queryset as suggested does indeed show my data, so the failure to display the items  is still puzzling me.

Comment: I finally found the true problem... Some CSS code was hiding the output.  Thanks again for your suggestions!